# Can a .net program written for windows work on osx?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, outlook

I recently wrote a small app which will grab contacts from microsoft Outlook and then create a csv and email to the head office.

The app works a treat but the only issue we have is some of our sales team use mac books with the mac version of office.

Is there a way in which the .net app which has been written in c# can work on the osx machines or is it a case of looking into writing it in a different language and seeing if there is a way of plugging into outlook.

Comment: Check with this posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745525/net-application-to-mac-os-x-application and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/330318ab-ec97-4f5a-b037-f91bbe248d52/

Comment: you may look into [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX), but if you're using office interop to read data from Outlook I highly doubt you can make it work as-is on Mac...

Comment: Vade, how are you connecting to MS Outlook? Even if using Mono or Java /C++ you would eventually be able to share same source code for the two platforms, it really depends on what you assume is installed in the client machine (Outlook version) and how you connect to it...

Comment: @ Davide - I connect to outlook using the outlook reference object libary atm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your C# program can work in OSX if Mono (.NET for Unix/Linux) is installed on it.

However, I don't think Office assemblies (the ones you referenced in your project) are going to work on OSX because those are wrapper .NET assemblies for Office COM native objects which are Windows OS dependent.

Comment: 1+. THis is not a :NET issue - it is one of interfacing with office.

Comment: Actually it IS a .nET Issue since the method he is communicating with OFFICE is what will determine if it will work in Mono.

Answer (score 3):

Application in DotNet can run into OSX when Mono in installed on the Mac Book, But not all of the exact code in DotNet. you can check your code with the MoMa(Mono Migration Analyzer) that **"is your code could run in Linux/Unix operation system with mono?"**

you can find the MoMa (it's free) in hear: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/moma/