# Compiling .NET IL to native code for Mac

Tags: .net, macos

Plain and simple I'm looking for a compiler that can take a .NET application (including dependencies) and compile the IL to native code for MacOSX similar to what MonoTouch does for iOS

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET application to Mac OS X application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745525/net-application-to-mac-os-x-application)

Comment: It's not a 100% duplicate. The request here is to compile to native code.

Comment: @Jason that question can be answered with "Use Mono" this question is "can I avoid to enforce the users to install Mono"