# Is it possible to build a Visual Studio application for Mac and Linux? Any "extensions" available

Tags: linux, vb.net, windows, macos, visual-studio-2015

I've created a nice application in Visual Studio. However, I want it to have multi-platform support. Is there any extension or anything I could implement to allow me to build my project for Windows, Mac and Linux users? Any suggestions or help would be helpful.

Thanks in advance,

Eddie

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET application to Mac OS X application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745525/net-application-to-mac-os-x-application)

Answer (score 2):

This other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745525/net-application-to-mac-os-x-application) on Stack Overflow is similar to yours, but only is asking about running on the application on Mac OSX. Most of the answers are suggesting to use the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/). Hope it helps a little!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Mono platform.  It is designed to let developers create cross-platform apps in .NET.
It will run on  Mac, Linux and  Windows.
In practice it is a bit clunky and not everything is available for Linux (e.g. WPF), but it might be a good solution for what you are trying to do.

http://www.mono-project.com/

Comment: Hi, how does it work? In Visual Basic? Or, is it a different IDE ? I'm only a intermediate when it comes to Software development. Thanks!

Comment: @EddieJibson it is for development in C#.  They have an IDE available:  http://www.monodevelop.com/

Comment: Yes, it's in C#. However, I'd prefer for it to be in Visual Studio as it makes things a lot easier, all I want to do is build it for Mac and Linux form Visual Studio. Any suggestions?